# Register an option in Android "click and hold" action

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-2.2-froyo

I'm creating an kind of download manager in Android. As an easy of use for this program I would like to include something that when the guy "click and hold" over some link (or over some already selected text of an link) in web browser, and option to "add to download Manager" shows up to him. I have no idea of how to do that...

Is it possible with Android SDK or do I need to use NDK? What classes should I look for?

----------------EDITED--------------------

Sorry, I think I wasn't very clear. I want to register an option for long click event in Android OS, not inside my application. Just like there is an "Share with GMail" option when you long click something.
I know it's possible cause Yahoo Mail application also have an "Share with Y! Mail" when I long click something, idependent of what application I'm using to long click, it can be Dolphin Web Broser, Opera Mobile/Mini, or even the default Android File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using content providers.  It is a pretty detailed, but here is the link to the documentation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

use onlongclick, see the link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: Yeah, I want to register an option to this kind of event, but I don't want that in my application, but in Android itself.
For example, when I install Yahoo mail and long click over an web link, when Android show me some options there is an "Share in Y! Mail". I want that my application register an option like that inside Android.

Comment: just setup the onlongclicklistener and have it call an alertdialog that gives the user the option of adding it to the download manager

Comment: But I want this longClick option to be displayed in any Web Browser that the user have in his Android (Dolphin, Opera, or the standard one).
Put this code inside my application will not do that. It will display long click only for my application.

Comment: ahhh, afaik you cannot modify them, android tries to make sure no one can modifies other peoples apps

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of what classes you would need, but it should definitely be available in the SDK.

Maybe google android SDK button?